# nodemailer with attachments using Sveltekit (using formdata)

Tags: nodemailer, form-data, sveltekit

I am trying to send a mail from a +page.server.ts file in Sveltekit using nodemailer and receiving the information with formdata.

This is my code for **+page.server.ts**

```
import type { Actions } from './$types';
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';

export const actions = {
    default: async ({ request }) => {
        const data = await request.formData();

        const newfile = data.get('file') as File;

        const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            ......
        });

        // send mail with defined transport object
        const info = await transporter.sendMail({
            from: 'xxx@.xxx.net', // sender address
            to: 'xxx@.xxx.net', // list of receivers
            subject: 'WEB Message: ', // Subject line
            html: 'testing',
            attachments: [
                {
                    filename: 'new_file.svg',
                    content: await newfile.arrayBuffer()
                }
            ]
        });

        console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
    }
} satisfies Actions;
```

My main question is how should I process the information of the **newfile** variable? and how should I send it in nodemailer?

I have tried it as:

```
content: newfile
content: newfile.stream
content: newfile.text
content: await newfile.arrayBuffer()
```

The error received is:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received an instance of ArrayBuffer
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:315:13)
    at Writable.end (node:internal/streams/writable:612:17)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/Users/ben/Development/Sites/outsourcing/node_modules/.pnpm/nodemailer@6.9.1/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/mime-node/index.js:977:46)
    at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:471:21) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trial and error this worked for me:

```
        const arrayBuffer = await newfile.arrayBuffer();
        const content = Buffer.from(arrayBuffer);
```

then

```
            attachments: [
                {
                    filename: newfile.name,
                    content
                }
            ]
```